# Struggling with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I would like to split a text but keep "a-zA-z" and "'" (single quote).

I need this:

```
let str = "-I'm (going crazy with) this*, so I'%ve ^decided ?(to ask /for help. I hope you'll_ help me before I go crazy!"
```

To be this:

```
let arr = ["i'm", "going", "crazy", "with", "this", "so", "I've", "decided", "to", "ask", "for", "help", "I", "hope", "you'll", "help", "me", "before", "I", "go", "crazy"]
```

Currently I have this:

```
function splitText(text) {
    let words = text.split(/\s|\W/);
    return words;
}
```

Obviously, this won't keep "I'm" nor "you'll", for example, which is what I need. I've tried a few combinations with W$, ^W and so on, but with not success.

All I want to keep is letters and "'" wherever there's a declination.

Help! Thanks!

Comment: `/[^a-z']+/gi` would do it

Comment: it didn't:

'what
'why
'you're
a
aasen
able
about

Comment: The title is very poor. Can you adjust it to something that actually describes the problem you're having so it can be searched by future visitors and curators? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
let str = "-I'm (going crazy with) this*, so I'%ve ^decided ?(to ask /for help. I hope you'll_ help me before I go crazy!";
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s']+/g, '').split(/\s+/);
console.log(str);
// => [ "I'm", "going", "crazy", "with", "this", "so", "I've", "decided", "to", "ask", "for", "help", "I",
//   "hope", "you'll", "help", "me", "before", "I", "go", "crazy" ]
```

**NOTES**:

- `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s']+/g, '')` - removes all chars other than letters, digits, whitespace and single quotation marks
- `.split(/\s+/)` - split with one or more whitespace chars.

**Also**, if you want to only keep `'` between word chars, you may use an enhanced version of the first regex:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s']+|\B'|'\B/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qXrYSW/1) with an input containing `'` not in the middle of the words.

Comment: it works like a charm, except for the single quotation at the beginning of a word (the fault is in my first explanation, though):  --'I'm-- becomes 'I'm. Could you please help me get rid of the single quote at the beginning of the word too? Thanks!

Comment: @Jason `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s']+|\B'|'\B/g`, see the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @Jason `str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s']+|\B'|'\B/g, '').split(/\s+/);`